# How to connect wiring for ceiling fan?

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

I'm trying to install a ceiling fan. There used to be one at this location which is now controlled by a wall switch. The ceiling box where the fan goes only has 2 black wires going down to the wall switch. It appears it was a white and black wire but only the black wire was spliced to the switch. How do I hook the fan up ?

Comment: "Spliced out"? What does that mean? The only question here is of polarity. Black to black, white to white.

Comment: I mean that there is only one wire that has a black and a white wire in it , and the black wire has been cut into and white one left together

Answer (score 1):

Did you already remove the other fan?

If there is another fan already there then just replace it using the same wiring configuration if it worked the way you wanted it to.

The new fan may have a light kit (you didn't mention that) and it sounds like you only have one switch so you will have to decide if you want the wall switch to turn on the fan or the light. The other one you will have to operate with the pull chain.

Happy New Year!

Comment: Or the wall switch can control power to both, with pullchains setting te overall behavior... which is a common way to wire these when putting them in as retrofits, since it keeps the convenience of being able to turn the whoke thing on and off from tne doorway..

Comment: Yes the fan was already removed . An electrician told me that one of the black wires was hot and the other neutral so I'm gonna try hooking up fan both ways black to black and then black to white

Comment: The wires should be black and white but may have discolored with age. The black wire (power wire) should go through the switch. The neutral (normally a white wire) should be connected to another white wire in the box with a wire nut.

Comment: My electrician used 3 conductor wire and replaced the single switch with a double switch so we can work the fan separate from the light when entering the room.